# XCode: Locking or timing out a view or its elements for a certain amount of time

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, locking, timeout

I'm trying to find a way to time out a screen on an iPhone after pressing a button for a certain amount of time. I'm trying to do this because my app sends a command that takes some time to process and I don't want the user to be able to press anything else or send out any other commands while this command is executing.

I've been searching for a few hours now and haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start processing things, set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `UIView` you don't want people messing with to `NO`, then reset it to `YES` when the processing is done.

Comment: Ah, this is great, thank you so much. I wish I wasn't such a Cocoa noob sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to lock your user out of your app for a significant amount of time.  It's just bad form.

If you still insist upon doing so, I suggest using an HUD-style progress indicator that covers the view, such as [**`SVProgressHUD`**](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD).

[image]

If you want to disable user interaction (disable touches) on the view, use the mask type of `SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient` or `SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack`.

Comment: @Resp: Be sure to mark it as an answer then if it solved your problem.